# How to sort by meta value?

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

How can I sort by meta value? In meta value I have "price" (float).

I make this query, but always get

> Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.

```
$posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=Notes&meta_value_num=price&order=ASC');
```

**Edit:**

```
meta_value value:
"a:6:{s:5:"width";s:3:"580";s:6:"**price**";s:3:"99"".
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Your meta value is a serialized array.

What you're asking it to get for you is all posts with a meta with the key `'Notes'` and the value `'price'`. Your meta value is not `'price'`, though, it's

```
a:6:{s:5:"width";s:3:"580";s:6:"price";s:3:"99"
```

The first thing you need to do to order by price is to start using a helpful key/value structure. I assume you're using something like this to store the post meta:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'foobar', array( 'width' => 580, 'price' => 99 ), true );
```

when your needs would indicate that you need to do something like this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'width', 580, true );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', 99, true );
```

Once you have your meta values saved in that format, you're going to want to use a `meta_query`:

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $my_query );
$my_query['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
         'key' => 'price',
         'value' => 0,
         'type' => 'SIGNED',
         'compare' => '>=',
    )
);
$my_query['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$my_query['order'] = 'ASC';
query_posts( $my_query );
```

Meta queries are new in WordPress 3.1, so you'll need to be using at least that version to do this.

Let me know if you run into problems!

Comment: Cool man, thank you very much - saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution can help you, I needed to control posts sort by meta_key and meta_value on every request so I created a filter this way:

```
/**
* Filter for every the loop request
* 
* @param mixed $request
*/
function request( $request ) {
    $option = $_REQUEST['mysortoption'] ? $_REQUEST['mysortoption'] : 'default';

    switch ( strtolower($option) ) {
        case 'most-viewed':
            $request['meta_key'] = 'most-viewed';
            $request['orderby'] = "meta_value";
            break;
        case 'hot':
            $request['orderby'] = 'comment_count';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return $request;
}
add_filter('request', 'request');
```

Ok, this solution is part of a big requirement but what we're doing here is just intercepting every request, verify is there is a special sort option I added before and apply the corresponding sort by meta.

Hope this helps you.