# How to sort post listing on a page using custom field value?

Tags: custom-field, customization

I need help in sorting lists of posts inside a static page by a custom field value. I'm currently using the code below but it is not sorting correctly.

```
<?php
            $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=15&order=DESC&meta_key=sorting&orderby=meta_value_number&tag='. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Tag', true));
            foreach ($postslist as $post) :
                setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to this question: [How to sort by meta value?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15839/wordpress-how-to-sort-by-meta-value)

Answer (score 0):

You Should use **meta_key_num** instead of **meta_key_number**, so args for get_posts would be like this:

```
    <?php

$post_list_args = array(
   'numberposts' => 15,
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'orderby' => 'meta_key_num',
   'meta_key' => 'sorting',
   'tag' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Tag', true),
);

$post_list = get_posts( $post_list_args );
foreach ( $post_list as $post ) :
   setup_postdata( $post );

?>
```